# Rewrite Apache Query_String

Tags: apache, web-services, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a query string URL: http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/home/qgis/project/map.qgs. I want to hind the map.qgs path in the variable MAP. Besides the map variable, there are some variables (version, request, service, etc).
Here is what I need:

RewriteRule:
Pattern: ^cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=map.qgs&(.*)$
Substitution: ^cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/home/qgis/project/map.qgs&(.*)$

Find bellow my unsuccessful attempt:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^map=([A-Za-z0-9.-_]+)$
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?(.*)$ cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?$1
```

Note: The map variable can show up in the pattern uRL anywhere among the other variables.

I wonder what I am missing on the code above

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.
The reason why your rule isn't working is because you can't test queryString in pattern of a RewriteRule.

You need  to change your rule's pattern to

```
  RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi$
```

With this change your htaccess rules will look like :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^map=([A-Za-z0-9./-_]+)/map.qgs$
RewriteRule ^/?cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi$ /cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: the RewriteRule still missing something. The query starts after qgis_maserv.fcgi? and then comes the second RewriteCond: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^map=([A-Za-z0-9./-_]+)\.qgs$
According to 2 RewriteCond variable MAP can have just a file name .qgs (Pattern)
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi\?$ /cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/home/qgis/project/%1 [NC,QSA,R,L]

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^map=map.qgs$
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi\?$ /cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/home/qgis/project/%1 [NC,QSA,R,L]

Comment: To test the rewrite rule I just gave a name to the MAP variable (map.qgs). But the rewrite rule still not doing the job.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine On
                #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=value
                #RewriteRule (.*) /path/ [R=302,L]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^map=/home/qgis/project/([A-Za-z0-9./-_]+).qgs$ [NC]
                RewriteRule ^/?cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi$ /cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?%1 [NC,QSA,R,L]
        </IfModule>

Comment: @HelpOverFlow Sorry couldn't reply your messages as the notifications were missing. Could you please let me know if this issue is resolved now? If you still  need my help with this you can ask. Thanks